# Delaying a drop down menu from hiding

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, settimeout

Thanks to you guys, my menu is now usable because the submenu displays long enough for the user to get their mouse to the links.  Unfortunately, it's not exactly right. The submenu closes even when the users mouse is over it.  I have added the HTML code below along with the revised js file code.  I'm thinking the problem is in the $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu); line.  Perhaps an alternative would be to have a timeout delay AFTER the openSubMenu function is called to at least give users 8 seconds or so before the submenu hides.  This would be an acceptable solution to me.

```
<!-- HTML menu code below -->
<ul class="myMenu">
<li class="menuHeader"><a href="#">Employees <img src="images/arrowdown.gif" alt="Employee Links" width="11" height="8" border="0"/></a>
<ul class="subMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>     
    </ul></li>
</ul>       

<!-- js file code below -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
    $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

    function openSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');    
    };

    function closeSubMenu() {
        var ul = $(this).find('ul');
        setTimeout(function(){
        ul.css('visibility', 'hidden');}, 10000);

    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `setTimeout` callback did nothing, you should put the code in the callback function. 
`setTimeout` is not something like `sleep`.

```
function closeSubMenu() {
    var ul = $(this).find('ul');
    setTimeout(function(){
        ul.css('visibility', 'hidden'); 
    }, 2000);
};
```

Comment: Thank you!  This solved one problem but unfortunately produced another.  Basically, my menu wouldn't stay open long enough for a user to choose an option.  I changed the 2000 ms to 10000 ms but this didn't work very well in IE8.  The code: $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu); closes the sub menu even when the users mouse is still over it.

Answer (score 0):

try something like that.  if you toggle to hide, then it'll delay for 3 sec before hide. if the toggle to show, $('#toggle-item') will clear the queue and show the item,

```
function toggle(show){

    if (show) {

        $('#toggle-item').stop().clearQueue().show();

    } else {

        $('#toggle-item').delay(3000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `setTimeout` command works like this `setTimeout(the function to execute, delay in milliseconds)`

so, this is what you need to do:

`setTimeout($(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden'),3000);`

note that from `$(this)` to `'hidden')` is the actual command. if that doesn't work, try this instead:

```
    //place this in your <head> section
    function closeDropDownFunction() {
    $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

    //then place this wherever the timeout needs to be
    setTimeout(closeDropDownFunction(), 3000);
```